# Set Message TTL to one hour RabbitMQ

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, amqp, ttl

How can I set the message TTL ( Not the Queue ) from either the

- Exchange ( The exchange sends to multiple queues )
- Message ( when publishing the message )
- Queue ( On the queue itself but again this is the Message TTL and not the Queue TTL )

I'm running RabbitMQ 3.x, Symfony 2.1.x and the [RabbitMqBundle](https://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle).

What I've tried:

- Setting the Message TTL when I make the queue itself from the RabbitMQ Admin UI

I set the message properties to `'x-message-ttl' => 3600000`. In the RabbitMQ config it looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "blah_queue",
    "vhost": "foobar",
    "durable": true,
    "auto_delete": false,
    "arguments": {
            'x-message-ttl' => 3600000
    }
},
```

this is the error I get:

```
PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-message-ttl'for queue
```

I tried setting in the config.yml ( symfony / https://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle / README )

this gives a bunch of errors with the AMQP library the bundle uses.

I tried modifying the AMQP library itself to allow the `x-message-ttl` message properties and I get an exception `Error sending data`.

Has anyone set the Message TTL using the RabbitMQBundle?

```
queue_options:    {name: 'blah_queue', arguments: {'x-message-ttl' => 3600000}}
```

Comment: I believe you want to do something like this: `arguments: {'x-message-ttl' : ['I', 3600000]}' look at [this test file](https://github.com/romainneutron/php-amqplib/blob/9165f99461c3455ddc93916ad0821e99b0d19c43/demo/queue_arguments.php) for the under lying library

Answer (score 1):

```
queue_options:    {name: 'blah_queue', arguments: {'x-message-ttl' : ['I', '3600000']}}
```

Comment: Sorry that was one of the options I tried already, it didn't work

Comment: This works correctly for me with Rabbit 2.8 and the latest versions of both RabbitMQBundle and php-ampqlib. Haven't test with 3.x releases of Rabbit, but perhaps the option has changed?

Comment: Also, you need to delete the queue before running a consumer/producer. You cannot add this argument to a queue which does not already have it.

Comment: Tested with RabbitMQ 3.0.1. Works fine.

Comment: I hacked it to work at the message level: https://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle/issues/80

Answer (score 1):

**I can set the queue message time to live from the rabbitmq management console like this:**

1. I'm using RabbitMQ 3.1.5 on Fedora Linux, visit this in the browser:

   http://your_rabbitmq_server.com:15672
2. Click "Queues" tab and scroll down to where it says: "Add a new queue"
3. Under the subsection: "Add a new queue", fill out these text boxes:

   ```
   Virtual host:             /
   Name:                     myqueue1
   Durability:               Durable
   Auto delete:              No
   Message TTL:     
   Auto expire: 
   Max length: 
   Dead letter exchange:
   Dead letter routing key: 

   Argument key      = x-message-ttl
   Argument value    = 3600000
   Argument datatype = number
   ```
4. Click OK to save it.

Now I could consume from the queue and the message will still be there for the specified time.